How can i implement a traceroute using raw sockets?
I am trying to create a traceroute program in UNIX using raw sockets. I'm kind of new to this, but I managed to gather some things from here and there and put them together. However, it doesn't work as intended; it seems like I can't trace outside my local network. What could I do?
unsigned short checksum(void *b, int len) {
    unsigned short *buf = b;
    unsigned int sum = 0;
    unsigned short result;

    for (sum = 0; len > 1; len -= 2)
        sum += *buf++;
    if (len == 1)
        sum += *(unsigned char *)buf;
    sum = (sum >> 16) + (sum & 0xFFFF);
    sum += (sum >> 16);
    result = ~sum;
    return result;
}

void trace_route(int client_socket, const char *ip_address) {
    int sock;
    struct sockaddr_in dest_addr;
    struct icmp icmp_pkt;
    struct timeval start, end;
    unsigned int ttl;
    socklen_t len = sizeof(dest_addr);
    
    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_ICMP);
    if (sock < 0) {
        perror("Socket creation failed");
        return;
    }

    memset(&dest_addr, 0, sizeof(dest_addr));
    dest_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    dest_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ip_address);

    for (ttl = 1; ttl <= 30; ttl++) {  // Max 30 hopuri
        // Setăm TTL-ul pentru fiecare pachet
        setsockopt(sock, IPPROTO_IP, IP_TTL, &ttl, sizeof(ttl));

        // Creăm pachetul ICMP (ping)
        memset(&icmp_pkt, 0, sizeof(icmp_pkt));
        icmp_pkt.icmp_type = ICMP_ECHO;  // Tipul de pachet este ICMP Echo Request
        icmp_pkt.icmp_code = 0;
        icmp_pkt.icmp_id = getpid();
        icmp_pkt.icmp_seq = ttl;
        icmp_pkt.icmp_cksum = checksum(&icmp_pkt, sizeof(icmp_pkt));

        gettimeofday(&start, NULL);
        
        // Trimitem pachetul
        if (sendto(sock, &icmp_pkt, sizeof(icmp_pkt), 0, (struct sockaddr*)&dest_addr, sizeof(dest_addr)) < 0) {
            perror("Send failed");
            continue;
        }

        // Așteptăm răspuns
        memset(&icmp_pkt, 0, sizeof(icmp_pkt));
        int response = recvfrom(sock, &icmp_pkt, sizeof(icmp_pkt), 0, (struct sockaddr*)&dest_addr, &len);
        
        gettimeofday(&end, NULL);

        // Măsurăm timpul de răspuns
        long rtt = (end.tv_sec - start.tv_sec) * 1000 + (end.tv_usec - start.tv_usec) / 1000;

        if (response < 0) {
            printf("Hop %d: Request Timed Out\n", ttl);
        } else {
            printf("Hop %d: %s (RTT: %ld ms)\n", ttl, inet_ntoa(dest_addr.sin_addr), rtt);
        }

        if (icmp_pkt.icmp_type == ICMP_ECHOREPLY) {
            printf("Trace completed.\n");
            break;
        }
    }

    close(sock);
}


I keep getting the same ip adress repeated 30 times
I don't really know what to try to fix it. I tried connected to different networks
